# SharedPreferences variable is only received and can be shown on a second execution

Tags: android

I searched all forums and solutions but none did the trick. I have an app that scans some text and receive the scan text and show it. This is the file where I get the scan results:

```
@Override
public void extractData(RomaniaIdFrontRecognizer.Result result)  {
    super.extractData(result);

    savePreferences("selected", result.getLastName());

    add(R.string.PPLastName, result.getLastName());
    add(R.string.PPFirstName, result.getFirstName());
    add(R.string.PPIdentityCardNumber, result.getCardNumber());
    add(R.string.PPSeries, result.getIdSeries());
    add(R.string.PPCNP, result.getCnp());
    add(R.string.PPNationality, result.getNonMRZNationality());
    add(R.string.PPPlaceOfBirth, result.getPlaceOfBirth());
    add(R.string.PPAddress, result.getAddress());
    add(R.string.PPIssuingAuthority, result.getIssuedBy());
    add(R.string.PPSex, result.getNonMRZSex());
    add(R.string.PPValidFrom, result.getValidFrom());
    add(R.string.PPValidUntil, result.getValidUntil());


}

    private void savePreferences(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("weightSetting", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

This part is being executed because if I put a toast, the message shows. 
And this is the file where I would want to receive the variable sent with sharedpreferences:

```
public class ResultActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ResultFragment.IResultFragmentActivity,
        FieldByFieldResultFragment.IFieldByFieldResultFragmentActivity {


    String a;
    String TempName, TempEmail ;
    String e;

    Bitmap bitmap;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    byte[] imageInByte;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Toast toast;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
    EditText nume;
    EditText prenume;
    EditText nr;
    EditText serie;
    EditText cnp;
    EditText nationalitate;
    EditText loc;
    EditText adresa;
    EditText emis;
    EditText sex;
    EditText start;
    EditText stop;
    String usern;
    public static final String EXTRAS_RESULT_TYPE = "EXTRAS_RESULT_TYPE";

    public enum ResultType {
        RECOGNIZER_BUNDLE,
        FIELD_BY_FIELD_BUNDLE
    }



    protected ViewPager mPager;

    protected RecognizerBundle mRecognizerBundle;
    protected FieldByFieldBundle mFieldByFieldBundle;

    protected ResultType mResultType;

    private ArrayList<Recognizer> mRecognizersWithResult;

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setActivityContentView();


    //    loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
     //   loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();


     //   String aa=loginDataBaseAdapter.getMagazin();

        String s = loadPreferences("selected");


       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mResultType = (ResultType) intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRAS_RESULT_TYPE);

        mRecognizerBundle = new RecognizerBundle();
        mFieldByFieldBundle = new FieldByFieldBundle();

        if (mResultType == null) {
            if (mRecognizerBundle.existsInIntent(intent)) {
                mResultType = ResultType.RECOGNIZER_BUNDLE;
            } else if (mFieldByFieldBundle.existsInIntent(intent)) {
                mResultType = ResultType.FIELD_BY_FIELD_BUNDLE;
            }
        }

        if (mResultType == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Results must be passed to ResultActivity!");
        }

        mPager = findViewById(R.id.resultPager);
        switch (mResultType) {
            case RECOGNIZER_BUNDLE:
                mRecognizersWithResult = new ArrayList<>();
                mRecognizerBundle.loadFromIntent(intent);
                for ( Recognizer< Recognizer, Recognizer.Result > r : mRecognizerBundle.getRecognizers() ) {
                    if ( r.getResult().getResultState() != Recognizer.Result.State.Empty ) {
                        mRecognizersWithResult.add( r );

                     //   String text = mRecognizersWithResult.get(0).toString();
                    //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                mPager.setAdapter(new RecognizerListFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
                break;
            case FIELD_BY_FIELD_BUNDLE:
              //  mFieldByFieldBundle.loadFromIntent(intent);
             //   mPager.setAdapter(new FieldByFieldBundleFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
             //   break;
        }

        TabPageIndicator indicator = findViewById(R.id.resultIndicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(mPager);

        indicator.setClipChildren(false);



    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // clear saved state to be sure that data is cleared from cache and from file when
        // intent optimisation is used





        mRecognizerBundle.clearSavedState();
        mFieldByFieldBundle.clearSavedState();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mResultType == ResultType.RECOGNIZER_BUNDLE) {
            mRecognizerBundle.saveState();
        } else if (mResultType == ResultType.FIELD_BY_FIELD_BUNDLE) {
            mFieldByFieldBundle.saveState();
        }
    }


    public void setActivityContentView() {
        setContentView(R.layout.result_menu);


    }


    private String loadPreferences(String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("weightSetting", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String load = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
        return load;

    }



    @Override
    public Recognizer< Recognizer, Recognizer.Result > getRecognizerAtPosition(int resultPosition) {
        if (resultPosition < 0 || resultPosition >= mRecognizersWithResult.size()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Recognizer with non empty result on requested position"
                    + " does not exist. Possible cause is that recognizer bundle state has been lost"
                    + " in intent transactions.");
        }
        //noinspection unchecked
        return mRecognizersWithResult.get(resultPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public FieldByFieldBundle getFieldByFieldBundle() {
        return mFieldByFieldBundle;
    }

    private class RecognizerListFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        RecognizerListFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ResultFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mRecognizersWithResult.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return ResultUtils.getRecognizerSimpleName(mRecognizersWithResult.get(position));
        }
    }

    private class FieldByFieldBundleFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        FieldByFieldBundleFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return FieldByFieldResultFragment.newInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return ResultActivity.this.getString(R.string.title_field_by_field_results);
        }

    }


    public void footerButtonClickHandler(View view) {

        // String sessionId= getIntent().getStringExtra("test");



        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "da", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // new RegisterAsyntaskNew().execute();


        ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resultValueee);

        // img.buildDrawingCache();
        // Bitmap bitmap = img.getDrawingCache();

        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();

        // RomanianIDFrontSideRecognitionResultExtractor myActivity2 = new RomanianIDFrontSideRecognitionResultExtractor();
        // myActivity2.InsertData();



        Img(imageInByte,e);

       // InsertData(nume.getText().toString(), prenume.getText().toString(), nr.getText().toString(), serie.getText().toString(),cnp.getText().toString(),nationalitate.getText().toString(), loc.getText().toString(),adresa.getText().toString(),emis.getText().toString(),sex.getText().toString(),start.getText().toString(),stop.getText().toString(),usern);




        finish();

    }



    public void InsertData(final String nume, final String prenume, final String nr, final String serie, final String cnp, final String nationalitate

            , final String locn, final String adresa, final String emis, final String sex, final String start, final String sfarsit,final String username){



        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String name = nume ;
                String pren = prenume ;
                String nr1 = nr;
                String serie1 = serie ;
                String cnp1 = cnp ;
                String nat = nationalitate ;
                String locn1 = locn ;
                String adresa1 = adresa ;
                String emis1 = emis ;
                String sex1 = sex ;
                String start1 = start ;
                String sfarsit1 = sfarsit ;
                String user1 = username ;

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", pren));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nr", nr1));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serie", serie1));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cnp", cnp1));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nat", nat));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locn", locn1));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("adresa", adresa1));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emis", emis1));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sex", sex1));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start", start1));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sfarsit", sfarsit1));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user1));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url");

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                    a = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                    // return EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity).trim();


                    ResultActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            // Toast.makeText(ResultActivity.this, a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            toast = Toast.makeText(ResultActivity.this, a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                            v.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#66ff33"));


                            int toastDuration = 5000;
                            CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
                            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(toastDuration, 1000) {
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    toast.show();
                                }

                                public void onFinish() {
                                    toast.cancel();
                                }
                            };

                            toast.show();
                            countDownTimer.start();

                        }
                    });






                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return "Data Inserted Successfully";
            }


        }

        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();

        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(nume, prenume,nr,serie,cnp,nationalitate,locn,adresa,emis,sex,start,sfarsit,username);

    }




    public void Img(final byte[] data,final String cnpimg){



        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String cnp1 = cnpimg ;

                Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
                byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                String ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", ba1));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cnp", cnp1));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://promotii.grupsapte.ro/php/scanid/img.php");

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                    //    a = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                    // return EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity).trim();


                    //   ResultActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    //        public void run() {
                    //            Toast.makeText(ResultActivity.this, a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //         }
                    //      });






                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return "Data Inserted Successfully";
            }


        }

        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();

        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute();

    }












}
```

The send-receive variable with shared preferences worked but now, i don't know the cause, first time I get a null variable and if I try it again then I receive what I scan first. So, the variable is shown only the second time with the value scan for the first time. Even if I try to put a simple text and send it, it will show only the second time I make the action. But I repeat, the file is getting executed because if I put a toast, it will show. I think that the receiving of the shared preferences variable is done first and then the code from the first file is being executed. I tried to put the code in oncreate, onresume but nothing did the trick. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You posted an unclear question. I read several time but i didn't understand clearly. you said 2nd time you are getting value from sharedpref that means you are saving into sharedpref where you want to receive. thats why first time getting null and 2nd time getting value ..

Comment: so: First time when I scan and trying to send the data with shared preferences i receive null. Only when I scan the second time I will receive the data that I scanned the first time. It's always one step behind.

Comment: provide code that store the data and from where you requesting the data ..  Do comment on your code and ignore unnecessary code while providing.

Comment: what is " add " method ?? what it does ?

Comment: Ok..I'll edit an update my question

Comment: let me know after update ..

Comment: So I have put a timer for 1 second when I receive the variables through shared preferences and did the trick. I don't know what mess up the process because this worked ok in the past month and all of the sudden the process of transmitting the through shared preferences was first and then all the other processes. Thanks for your attention and time. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to put a delay of 1 second for the process of receiving thorugh shared preferences. See below:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // clear saved state to be sure that data is cleared from cache and from file when
    // intent optimisation is used


    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Your logic here...

            // When you need to modify a UI element, do so on the UI thread.
            // 'getActivity()' is required as this is being ran from a Fragment.
            ResultActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This code will always run on the UI thread, therefore is safe to modify UI elements.

                    String a = loadPreferences("nume");

                    String b= loadPreferences("prenume");
                    String c= loadPreferences("nr");
                    String d= loadPreferences("serie");
                    e= loadPreferences("cnp");
                    String f= loadPreferences("nationalitate");
                    String g= loadPreferences("locn");
                    String h= loadPreferences("adresa");
                    String i= loadPreferences("emis");
                    String j= loadPreferences("sex");
                    String k= loadPreferences("start");
                    String l= loadPreferences("sfarsit");

                    usern= "";


                       String s = Normalizer.normalize(f, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
                       String bla = s.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");

                         String t = Normalizer.normalize(h, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
                        String bla1 = t.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");

                       String a1 = Normalizer.normalize(a, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
                       String bla2 = a1.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");

                       String b1 = Normalizer.normalize(b, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
                       String bla3 = b1.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");


                       String g1 = Normalizer.normalize(g, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
                       String bla4 = g1.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");



                    nume = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nume);
                    nume.setText(bla2);

                    prenume = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.prenume);
                    prenume.setText(bla3);

                    nr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nrserie);
                    nr.setText(c);

                    serie = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serie);
                    serie.setText(d);

                    cnp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cnp);
                    cnp.setText(e);

                    nationalitate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nationalitate);
                    nationalitate.setText(bla);

                    loc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loc);
                    loc.setText(bla4);

                    adresa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adresa);
                    adresa.setText(bla1);

                    emis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emis);
                    emis.setText(i);

                    sex = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sexx);
                    sex.setText(j);

                    start = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.start);
                    start.setText(k);

                    stop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.stop);
                    stop.setText(l);


                   // String s = loadPreferences("selected");


                 //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000); // End of your timer code.


    mRecognizerBundle.clearSavedState();
    mFieldByFieldBundle.clearSavedState();
}
```